# Spark Mongo connector: Upsert only one attribute in MongoDB connection

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, upsert

Let's say I have the following Mongo document:

```
{
 "_id":1, 
 "age": 10,
 "foo": 20
}
```

and the following Spark DataFrame `df`:

```
_id | val
 1  | 'a'
 2  | 'b'
```

and now I want to append the `val` from the dataframe to the Mongo document...

Using the [MongoDB Spark connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/), I can use the *default upserting* logic via "_id" append, meaning if the "_id" in Spark dataframe and Mongo document matches, Mongo connector will not create a new document, but rather update the old one.

But! The update basically behaves like *replace* - if I do the following:

```
df
.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
.mode("append")
.option('spark.mongodb.output.uri','mongodb://mongo_server:27017/testdb.test_collection')
.save()
```

The collection will look like:

```
[   
    {
     "_id":1, 
     "val": 'a'
    },
   {
     "_id":2, 
     "val':'b' 
    }
]
```

and I would like to obtain this:

```
[   
    {
     "_id":1, 
     "age": 10,
     "foo": 20
     "val": 'a'
    },
   {
     "_id":2, 
     "val':'b' 
    }
]
```

---

**My questions are**:

- is there way (some option) to make the Spark connector behave the way
  I want it to behave?
- Sure, I can first read the documents from Mongo to Spark, enrich
  them with the "val" attribute and write/append it back to the Mongo. What is I/O of this operation? Is it a full load (reading all documents and then
  replacing all attributes) or is it somewhat clever (like reading all
  documents but appending only the "val" attribute, not
  replacing the entire document)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there way (some option) to make the Spark connector behave the way I want it to behave?

Yes, you can set the `replaceDocument` to `false`. For example, using [MongoDB connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) v2.2.2 and Apache Spark v2.3 in Python:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
               .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://host101:27017/dbName.collName").load()
df.first() 
> Row(_id=1.0, age=10.0, foo=20.0)

# Create a dataframe 
d = {'_id': [1, 2], 'val':['a', 'b']}
inputdf = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
sparkdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(inputdf)

# Write to Spark 
sparkdf.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
             .mode("append").option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://host101:27017/dbName.collName")
             .option("replaceDocument", "false")
             .save()

# Result 
+---+----+----+---+
|_id| age| foo|val|
+---+----+----+---+
|1.0|10.0|20.0|  a|
|2.0|null|null|  b|
+---+----+----+---+
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot @Wan

Answer (score 0):

As of spark connector version 3.X, **replaceDocument** has been deprecated.

To achieve what you want, in spark connector 3.X+ you need to set **operationType** to 'update' (not the default 'replace'). You also want to set **upsertDocument** to True.

Read more here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/write/